# Two colors on one material on many objects with one blinking at a time

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I need a cycles material that has two colors, say red and blue. This material is assigned to many objects. While animating, only one random object can be red at a time, the rest must be blue. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the pass index (= Object Index in Object Info Node) to mix the shaders. You can animate it if the blue object should change over time.

[image]
[image]
[image]